# Error while upgrading to pip 7.1.10 on Windows 8.1 (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, windows-8.1, pip

```
$ C:\Python27> pip install --upgrade pip

You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Collecting pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=b108384a762825ec20
345bb9b5b7209f

Using cached pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 6.0.8
    Uninstalling pip-6.0.8:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-6.0.8
```

previous version of pip is gone but i get this exception after that :

```
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):


File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main status = self.run(options, args) 
                               .
                               .
                               .

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

I have upgrade **setuptools** and **distribute**  , also i tried to install pip manualy and got this :

```
$ C:\Python27> pip install 7.1.10
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting 7.1.10
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement 7.1.10
  No distributions at all found for 7.1.10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue , then i consulted the pip documentation and this is how they have recommended to upgrade pip :

for Windows :

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

for Linux :

```
pip install -U pip
```

For further reference check this[Link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html)

Comment: I had to run `easy_install -U pip` in my virtual environment as others have suggested

Answer (score 7):

[This bugreport](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2669) suggests doing

`easy_install -U pip`

Comment: this one worked for me, the former approved answer didnt

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I will toss in this:  I could not install pip with ANY of the commands until I saw your post to use "easy_install -U pip"

All other attempts resulted in

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 1):

I went on a different route. My first attempt at upgrading with `pip install --upgrade pip` didn't work on my Windows 10 PC. After opening a command prompt (cmd) I first did

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

and it gave me

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.2
    Uninstalling pip-1.5.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-1.5.2
Successfully installed pip-7.1.0
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The funny thing is that I was trying to upgrade from pip 6.1.1 to 8.0.2. But, hey, I'll take this upgrade too. Their suggested command `

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

did the final job

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.0
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.0
Successfully installed pip-8.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled pip first and than it worked.

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```